# Show tag icons instead of tag text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

I would like show tag icons instead of tag icons.
As an example, Instead of the tag text "Photoshop" I would like to show Photoshop icon.
Any help would be cordially appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to make an icon for each tag, then use the tag name to build a path to the icon.

```
<img src="/icons/<?php echo $tagName; ?>.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do that with [tag images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tag-images/) plugin